# PHP Image upload fails (Image taken from a mobile)

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I am facing a strange issue with PHP, can't seems to find the reason why this is happening. upload script which on Codeigniter works fine with images and uploads even larger files. but when I tried to upload and image which is being taken from a mobile device the script fails and the $_POST data goes missing.

Then I tried opening that image on PS and re-saved it and this time I even reduced the compression and made the file size larger  than the original image, the new file is being uploaded without even any issue. but not the original file keep making the POST data go missing

anyone has experienced this issue ?

```
<form class="upload" action="upload/do_upload" id="media_upload" method="POST"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="media_title" name="heading">
<input  type="file" name="file">
</form>


<?php

public function do_upload(){

$this->input->post() // This returns false

var_dump($_POST) // This is empty

}

?>
```

Comment: Post HTML form and controller action.

Comment: Do you mean you're having a problem with the upload script from a mobile device? Or that any image derived from a mobile camera - no matter if that image is transferred to a pc first - will not upload? You could convert your upload script to a REST service and pass all images as base64 encoded byte string. That's how we do it for mobile apps.

Comment: not what he meant. edit your question with all relevant code. do not post code as comments

Comment: @KaiQing sorry about that. I've edited my question and have added the code also. and this is an image copied to PC and tried to upload through Chrome

Comment: okay just tried this outside of codeigniter, with core PHP code, still fails and POST data goes missing for that certain image

Comment: It is odd this should only be doing this for images from a mobile device. You sure that relative action path is always hitting your upload script?

Comment: other image upload attempts just works fine, latest thing that I learnt is that, it's only for certain images this issue occur, I tried a few other images from the same device some goes on and some fails in the same way I mentioned above